# Why php page keep loading?

Tags: php, apache, loading

I am running php 5.2.6 with apache 2.
On my localhost, some pages keep loading forever with Firefox.
Konqueror works fine.
From another computer using Firefox works as well.
I looked at the network with ethereal and 200 ok is send and no more data is transiting.

any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: can you paste the source code of one of the pages you have this problem with?

Comment: Obvious question but are there any plugins that may be at fault?

Answer (score 2):

The forever loader could happen for a number of reasons. My first guess would be that an embedded flash is to blame, or that you are trying to load an image or another script that is nonexistent. In any case, it is difficult to give you any advice without the source code.

Also try using firebug to see what is being loaded.

If all else fails try to restart firefox, it can be up to some very strange things from time to time :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a long time ago but I don't see an answer to the question asked. Anyway, I encountered this problem too and my mistake was that I entered the address on the browser wrong: 
`localhost/80` instead of `localhost:80` (note the semi-colon). 
Ensure you use a semi-colon between `localhost` and `port`, otherwise you'll just be trying to load a non-existent page.

Answer (score 0):

Misuse of document.open/write is another possible cause of ‘loading forever’. Impossible to say without seeing some code though.